# Python synchronizarion

Tags: python, synchronization

Trying to create a synchronized database calls with Python. I am implementing a reader-writer solution so that either multiple threads can be reading from the database at the same time or multiple threads can be writing to the database at the same time.

I think I have a deadlock problem with my code but I can't figure out how to solve it. When running my program everything starts off fine but after many writes, a couple of reads happen and then the program freezes. No writes or reads are happening.

```
from threading import *

mutex = RLock() # RLock so only one thread can lock and unlock
global read_count, writer_count # Keep track of number of reading and writting threads
read_lock = Lock() # Updated 
write_lock = Lock() # Updated  # Initialize the locks
read_count = 0 # Updated 
writer_count = 0 # Updated 

 def read_from_db(self, sql):
        mutex.acquire()
        global read_count, writer_count
        if writer_count > 0:
            mutex.release() #release mutex to avoid deadlock
            read_lock.acquire() # Get the read_lock or wait until able to get it
        else:
            mutex.release()

        mutex.acquire()
        if read_count == 0:
            write_lock.acquire() # Get the write lock so writers can't get it while read thread is reading

        read_count += 1
        mutex.release()

        # read from DB 

        mutex.acquire()
        read_count -= 1
        if read_count <= 0:
            write_lock.release() #release the write lock
        mutex.release()

    def write_to_db(self):
        global read_count, writer_count

        mutex.acquire()
        if read_count > 0:
            mutex.release() #release mutex to avoid deadlock
            write_lock.acquire() #get the write lock or wait until able to get it
        else:
            mutex.release()

        mutex.acquire()
        if writer_count <= 0:
            read_lock.acquire() #Get the read_lock so that no reads happen while writing 

        writer_count += 1
        mutex.release()

        # write to db

        mutex.acquire()
        writer_count -= 1
        if writer_count == 0: # Updated 
            read_lock.release()
        mutex.release()
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about your problem?

Comment: It seems that `read_from_db` never releases `read_lock` if it acquires it.

Comment: `read_lock` and `write_lock` are the same Lock instance.

Comment: @quamrana I update the code in `read_fom_db` to `if writer_count <= 0:` then acquire the `read_lock` but the same problem is happening.

Comment: @Rawing updated code so that `read_lock` and `write_lock` are initialized separately  but problem is still happening

Comment: I cannot see any change to `read_from_db`. `read_lock` is only mentioned once. If you have a `read_lock.acquire()` in a method, then there should be a `read_lock.release()` as well.

Comment: @quamrana there is a `read_lock.release()` in the read_from_db method. It's the second to last line.

Comment: To me it reads: `write_lock.release() #release the write lock`